# jQuery textarea validation with radio button

Tags: jquery, validation

I am developing a survey system.

table answer:
field :`id, answer, answer_value, valdt.`

if answer=(please specify the time in the comments box) i put the value in valdt=1 otherwise its 0.

whatever if surveyor click this radio button the comment box text is required.

my code for the radio button is

```
$n1=$db->get_results("SELECT * FROM question where client='$client' and  status='1' order by `id`");

 foreach($n1 as $n2)
{
$s1=$db->get_results("SELECT * FROM answer where qid='$n2->id' ");
foreach($1 as $s2)
{
<input type="radio" name='ans[<?php echo $s2->id?>]' value="<?php echo $s2->id?>" validate="required:true" />
}
Comments:<textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="cmnt[<?php echo $n2->id?>]" ></textarea>
}
```

I want to validate if user clicks the radio button ( valdt=1 ) then the corresponding comment box text should be required, otherwise not.

I tried to solve this but alert message trigger but wont validate the comment field
I put the code inside the validation field but it wont work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#form1").validate();
function getNum(element, attrPrefix) {
var prefix = attrPrefix;
var num = element.attr("id").substring((prefix.length));
return num;
}
$(":radio").change(function() {
var num = getNum($(this), "r_");
if ($("#r_"+num).not(":checked")) {
alert(' Please Enter the comment in comment box ');
} else {
alert(' Please Enter Comment in Comment Box ');
return false;
}
return true;
});
```

Comment: do you want server-side or client-side validation?

Comment: @AkamOmer  sir how to validate in client side. can you please explain?

Comment: @AkamOmer  i need client side validation

Comment: if you familiar with jQuery, its very simple, disable the textarea by default, but when user checked the radio box, then enable it, if he forgot to write then onblur event can help you to disable it again. You can also use native JavaScript.

Comment: @AkamOmer I am a biginer in jquery,  sir can you just explain. where to display if(s2->valtd==1) just guide me sir.

Comment: @AkamOmer the survey system "www.sisadubai.com/survey/" user "srvdemo" password "srvdemo" if user click the  answer  "Please comment in the comment box" then the validation should be occur. plz suggest me.

Comment: I will update once I solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pages uses http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ validation, I worked with this example:

```
<input class="comment_check" name="check[116]" type="checkbox"> please check 
for comment<br>
<textarea cols="55" name="nn[116]" rows="5" validate="required:'input[name=check[116]]:checked'"></textarea>
```

it worked for me, you can print this checkbox like other fields

```
<input class="comment_check" name="check[<?php echo $n2->id?>]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $n2->id?>">
```

Comment: it's not work <textarea  rows="5" cols="55" name="nn[<?php echo $n2->id?>]" id="comment" validate="required:'input[name=check[<?php echo $n2->id;?>]]:checked'" ></textarea>

Comment: I tested with saved page on my PC, it works, however, you might print it in another way, let me see it on the real page

Comment: sir it only validate one filed i code like that                        <input type="radio" name='ans[<?php echo $n2->id?>]' value="<?php echo $s2->id?>" validate="required:true" id="r[<?php $n2->valdt == 1 ? print $survey1->id : print 'nothing'?>]" />                       in text box                                                  <textarea  rows="5" cols="55" name="nn[<?php echo $n2->id?>]" validate="required:'input[id=r[<?php print $n2->id;?>]]:checked'" ></textarea> but this validate only one filed plz help me i need to complete this today. or give some idea

Comment: I tried and changed some code but It only trigger the alert field validate plz sir help me.

Comment: can you show me what you tried? you must show me that you put this also (<input class="comment_check" name="check[<?php echo $n2->id?>]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $n2->id?>">)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo utilizing the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="radio" name="ans[]" id="ans" value="" />
    <textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="cmnt[]"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The plugin is initialized on your form by calling `.validate()` within a `document.ready`.  Your rules and options are passed inside the `.validate()` function and fields are identified by `name`.  Since you want the `required` rule to be conditional upon the radio button, use a `depends:` function within the rule for the `textarea`.  The `textarea` will then only be required if the radio box is selected.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            "cmnt[]": {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element){
                        return $("#ans").prop("checked");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        //  other rules and options
    });

});
```

**Working Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/3Nht6/

**Documentation for options**:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Comment: first, it must be checkbox not radio, and second, there are many comment fields, therefore, using ID for selector is not good idea.

Comment: @AkamOmer, First, in case you missed it, the question is titled, "jQuery textarea validation with **radio** button" and the OP is using a radio button in his code.  Second, my answer is only a single example the OP should modify to whatever suits his needs.  Since a specific button must correspond to a specific `textarea`, he can only use something specific to target, like the `id`.

Comment: @Sparky sir but this validate all radio button i need if the database column(valdt) value ==1 only the text box should be validate otherwise not.

Comment: @ukdub, it's a demo sample for you to learn from and modify to suit your needs.  But no, validation of the field in my demo depends only on the one targeted radio button, not all of them.

Comment: @Sparky can you give some tips how to do that? any idea?